# Há alguma maneira de formatar uma máscara de data dentro de uma tabela?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

No caso a informação é puxada de um banco de dados e não quero coloca-la dentro de um input. Há alguma maneira?

```
<td id="outra_data"><?php echo utf8_encode($dados['data_aprovacao']);?></td>
```

Comment: Você pode [edit] o post a qualquer momento dando mais detalhes sobre o formato original dos dados, a razão de estar usando uma função de conversão de caracteres, o resultado pretendido e o que não saiu como esperado na sua tentativa (fornecendo um [mcve] do problema). Da forma como está. tem muitas incógnitas na dúvida que podem afetar o resultado.

Comment: ????? What??????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a função date `echo date('d/m/Y', $dados['data_aprovacao']);`

Comment: A informação do banco está no padrão americano, essa função reverte para o padrão BR?Grato pela resposta!

Comment: @EmilioSaymon exatamente! funcionando não esqueça de validar a resposta, grato!

Comment: Algo está fazendo com que o erro " _A non well formed numeric value encountered in_" e "_Warning: date() expects parameter 2 to be long, string given in_" abaixo o meu código:
<pre>
<td><?php echo date("d-m-Y", $dados['ped_data_emissao']);?></td>
      <td><?php echo utf8_encode($dados['status_nome']);?></td>
      <td><?php echo date("d-m-Y",$dados['data_aprovacao']);?></td>
</pre>

Comment: Teste um date de cada vez. Verifique se seus campos vem do banco com formato date. Você pode também codificar as datas, assim: 
$dtemissao = strtotime($dados['ped_data_emissao']);
echo date("d-m-Y", $dtemissao);

Comment: Vou testar dessa forma, muito obrigado.

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo deu certo de primeira VALEU!!!! Eternamente grato! Abs!